# openmp with nested loops and function call

Tags: c++, openmp

I have a few nested loops and I put the first one in parallel mode. `apar` and `mpar` are structs whose values are modified in the loop and then function `breakLogic` is called which generates a struct which i store in a pre created vector of those structs.
one, two ... have been declared earlier in the function.

I have tried to include ordered and critical to ensure accuracy but i am still getting incorrect results.

```
#pragma omp parallel for ordered private(appFlip, atur, apar, mpar, i, j, k, l, m, n) shared(rawFlip)
for(i=0; i<oneL; i++)
    {
         initialize mpar
         #pragma omp critical
         apar.one = one[i];
         for(j=0; j<twoL; j++)
         {
             apar.two = two[j];
             for(k=0; k<threeL; k++)
             {
                  apar.three = floor(three[k]*apar.two);
                  appFlip = applyParamSin(rawFlip, apar);
                  for(l=0; l< fourL; l++)
                  {
                      mpar.four = four[l];
                      for(m=0; m<fiveL; m++)
                      {
                          mpar.five = five[m];
                          for(n=0; n<sixL; n++)
                          {
                              mpar.six = add[n];
                              atur = breakLogic(appFlip,  mpar, dt);
                              #pragma omp ordered
                              {
                                  sinResVec[itr] = atur;
                                  itr++;
                              }
                          }
                      }
                  }
                  r0(appFlip);
              }
         }
    }
```

Or is this code not conducive for parallelism? Are there any tools for g++ which can profile code for parallel processing and indicate potential issues?

This modified code works but gives no performance improvement.

Comment: Note that there are no conditionals in your code, therefore correct `itr` values can be computed directly instead of using increments in the innermost loop, thus you could get rid of `ordered`. Then you also need to make `apar` and `mpar` `private`, unless there are members of those structures that are shared between threads. With private variables you can also get rid of the `critical` constructs. Note that the outermost `critical` protects the entire loop and therefore the inner `critical`'s are superficial.

Comment: do i need to make l, m, n, o also private?

Comment: r0 is for dereferencing appFlip

Comment: If you're using g++ then define all your variables when you use them (e.g. for(int i=0; ...) and don't worry about explicitly declaring everything public and private.  That's only for people still using ANSI/gnu89 C.  Just remember that everything defined inside the parallel construction is private and everything outside is shared.  It will make your code a lot cleaner and personally I think easier to understand.  And don't compare performance without optimization on.

Comment: what do you mean by "don't compare performance without optimization on"? Isn't the whole point of parallelism performance improvement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You original code can be paralleled by a few modifications.

- set `apar` and `mpar` as `firstprivate`. `apar` and `mpar` should be thread local variables and be initialized when entering the `parallel for` region;
- remove all `critical` and `ordered` clauses, including the one in the `parallel for` directive. they are not working as your expected;
- calculate `iter` with `i`,`j`,`k`,`l`,`m`,`n` to remove the dependency.

.

```
iter=(((i*twoL+j)*threeL+k)*fourL+m)*fiveL+n;
sinResVec[itr] = atur;
```

### update

See here for more details of OpenMP, especially the differences between `private` and `firstprivate`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt15eb9t.aspx

Comment: Thanks Eric! Slight error/type on my part, apar.three is dependent on apar.two. Does this change anything?

Comment: and keep all i...n as private in parallel construct?

Comment: another question? you haven't mentioned anything about atur, appFlip etc. does keeping them private or firstprivate make any difference?

Comment: keeping them private as your existing code is fine. You could set them to `firstprivate` only if you want to initialize them when entering the parallel for region. Variables like `j` are explicitly initialized in the code, so `firstprivate` it is useless.